# Mediaelement.js simple audio playlist skin

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio, mediaelement.js

I've been searching the documentation of mediaelement.js for a Playlist skin( or atleast a skin that has previous and forward button) does such thing exist? I've seen examples online that has a previous and next button.  I was aiming for  something like this.

[image]

Comment: You mean embedding buttons to mediaelement controls to navigate to the previous/next track? Do the other two official skins (ted and wmp) support that feature?

Comment: Yes, Exactly, I was wondering if there's a skin for that. the playlist itself or the list of songs will be just dynamically loaded. so I don't need the whole playlist UI,just the previous and next track button

Comment: I don't think that mediaelement has native buttons for that. You could extend in size mediaelement control bar and add your own buttons with CSS, and then dynamically build this feature using Jquery.

Comment: if so, do you know where can I get any royalty free buttons? like the one above?

Comment: You could search the web. The hard part is embedding those buttons into mediaelement control bar and make it look native-like buttons. This is an interesting topic, it has been among my concerns in the past.

Comment: I am currently working on it, as of now I finally got the loop to work.

Comment: That's nice! You could share some code with us and let us help you when needed.

Comment: I finally got to add the previous button to my player, it is working like charm on my custom playlist, the previous button is looks like a native in my player. Once  I finish the source code I'll upload it on github.

Comment: Can you please tell me how you made that work? I mean next and previous play logic.

Answer (score 1):

You can extend this plugin by hark.com

https://github.com/hark/mediaelement-plugins

Example:

Previous Button:

```
(function($){
  MediaElementPlayer.prototype.buildprevious = function(player, controls, layers, media){
    var loop = $('<div class="mejs-button mejs-previous-button">' +      
      '</div>')
      // append it to the toolbar
      .appendTo(controls)
      // add a click toggle event
      .click(function(){
        // window.open(player.options.logo.link, '_blank');
        player.options.prevFunc.apply(this);
      });
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Then you can add this to the options in mediaelement.js

```
prevFunc: function(){
    // add previous functionality here
    alert("Previous!");
},
```